# jQuery UI Tabs and ajax form with mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, forms, tabs

Having problems with this setup what im trying to do is like so.

**Steps**

1. Fill out all elements of a `Ajax.BeginForm()`.
2. Click submit
3. The Ajax form then renders a partial view.
4. The partial view has a list of tabs that handle different tasks.
5. All tabs essentially have their own partial view.
6. When each partial view is loaded they perform the necessary queries for that specific tab.
7. Render the necessary data.
   (This is supposed to be done all in AJAX.)

I have no problems adding the jquery tabs and setting different actions to them and they work with their default ajax calls but as soon as I add `Ajax.BeginForm()` to the page they don't work with their default ajax calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, I used `Ajax.ActionLink()` to do the click-able tabs and mimicked the jQuery tabs UI this works well for me in terms of finalizing a solution.

This also works parallel with `Ajax.BeginForm()`